# Method forwarding on methods which contain Spring's @Transactional annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I have a service implementation which looks sort of like the following:

```
class FooImpl implements Foo {

   @Override
   @Transactional(...)
   public void doSomething(String baz) {
       return this.doSomething(Arrays.asList(new String[] { baz }));
   }


   @Override
   @Transactional(...)
   public void doSomething(List<String> bazList) {
        // do something crazy
        return null;
   }

}
```

I want to understand, what is happening here?  I'm calling a method with the `@Transactional` annotation from another method with the `@Transactional` annotation (method forwarding)...

**My question**:
Is what I have above creating any strange situations?  It seems to be working correctly, so I think that the outer transaction is being used and a new one is not being created.  Is this correct?  Also, any tips on how I could verify/debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a typical situation. `@Transactional` has a `propagation` property. This property defines the behaviour in case when a `@Transactional` method is invoked - whether a new transaction is needed, whether an existing transaction is needed, etc.

By default the propagation is `REQUIRED`, which means - a new transaction will be started if none exists; otherwise the existing will be used.

[Read here about transaction propagation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html#tx-propagation).

Another thing to mention here is that (in some configuration scenarios) in case you are calling methods of the same class, the transaction interceptor is not triggered, and so the propagation is not taken into account at all. So in your case, it is most likely that the `@Transactional` on the 2nd method is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using JDK proxies:

The second `@Transactional` will never even be invoked.  When you use JDK proxies for AOP, the advice only gets applied to the method when the call is made against the proxied bean.  When you call another method on the same class, the call isn't passing through the code that spring 'wraps' your method in when it creates the bean.  If you needed that to happen you would have to ask the ApplicationContext for a reference to the bean proxy that it created.

As an aside, `Collections,singletonList` !

Comment: Ahhh, singletonList rocks!  Thanks, I'm still a bit new to Java land.